# Solve minimization question in R using dynamic program

Tags: r, optimization, dynamic, path, nodes

I am currently trying to find a solution to a transportation problem. I have a table with the travel times from 30 customers to each other. The goal is to use dynamic program to go from this table with direct durations to a table with shortest duration possible (via possible subtours between pairs of customers)

I have no clue how to solve this. The question states "Let ,, be the shortest (in duration) path between customer  and , using only nodes 0 to  as intermediaries."

Is there someone who can help me with this?

Thank you in advance. :-)

to use only nodes 0 to k as intermediates.

[image: Here is a picture of the table]

```
structure(list(ID = 1:30, X1 = c(0L, 98L, 132L, 245L, 17L, 69L, 
139L, 112L, 207L, 35L, 249L, 43L, 215L, 62L, 152L, 237L, 59L, 
119L, 45L, 59L, 23L, 12L, 16L, 66L, 177L, 31L, 118L, 165L, 117L, 
193L), X2 = c(37L, 0L, 74L, 176L, 91L, 111L, 143L, 208L, 202L, 
40L, 172L, 101L, 163L, 51L, 220L, 180L, 48L, 98L, 45L, 62L, 91L, 
9L, 50L, 145L, 198L, 48L, 3L, 163L, 159L, 176L), X3 = c(118L, 
10L, 0L, 138L, 108L, 115L, 221L, 274L, 231L, 89L, 197L, 36L, 
175L, 93L, 174L, 184L, 13L, 109L, 109L, 22L, 172L, 91L, 12L, 
149L, 140L, 108L, 8L, 133L, 168L, 139L), X4 = c(252L, 137L, 112L, 
0L, 248L, 276L, 373L, 350L, 353L, 137L, 31L, 186L, 49L, 170L, 
325L, 81L, 117L, 184L, 175L, 185L, 279L, 182L, 120L, 205L, 130L, 
132L, 133L, 226L, 158L, 67L), X5 = c(40L, 93L, 118L, 188L, 0L, 
38L, 147L, 106L, 208L, 46L, 228L, 26L, 208L, 54L, 163L, 212L, 
81L, 49L, 45L, 84L, 12L, 82L, 114L, 81L, 173L, 67L, 52L, 63L, 
146L, 156L), X6 = c(54L, 117L, 143L, 296L, 74L, 0L, 78L, 97L, 
218L, 52L, 239L, 47L, 267L, 111L, 216L, 269L, 167L, 91L, 105L, 
99L, 16L, 117L, 95L, 15L, 264L, 136L, 148L, 100L, 145L, 242L), 
    X7 = c(143L, 145L, 208L, 302L, 130L, 86L, 0L, 84L, 308L, 
    151L, 348L, 102L, 305L, 139L, 254L, 272L, 156L, 182L, 87L, 
    214L, 110L, 82L, 145L, 59L, 283L, 98L, 171L, 192L, 211L, 
    228L), X8 = c(142L, 195L, 238L, 336L, 161L, 80L, 2L, 0L, 
    289L, 135L, 342L, 134L, 307L, 169L, 197L, 347L, 261L, 143L, 
    128L, 243L, 52L, 128L, 169L, 97L, 318L, 214L, 229L, 225L, 
    287L, 288L), X9 = c(230L, 238L, 217L, 264L, 229L, 154L, 299L, 
    269L, 0L, 210L, 335L, 204L, 342L, 260L, 25L, 258L, 264L, 
    76L, 170L, 222L, 126L, 193L, 272L, 203L, 218L, 186L, 214L, 
    120L, 240L, 207L), X10 = c(2L, 30L, 34L, 186L, 75L, 96L, 
    161L, 179L, 244L, 0L, 199L, 17L, 181L, 59L, 240L, 178L, 101L, 
    117L, 1L, 48L, 79L, 72L, 24L, 60L, 236L, 5L, 32L, 151L, 203L, 
    133L), X11 = c(243L, 191L, 114L, 38L, 164L, 211L, 295L, 370L, 
    350L, 211L, 0L, 174L, 14L, 166L, 278L, 164L, 165L, 223L, 
    252L, 129L, 201L, 196L, 201L, 271L, 98L, 199L, 209L, 219L, 
    168L, 62L), X12 = c(22L, 14L, 64L, 164L, 68L, 113L, 117L, 
    115L, 208L, 8L, 239L, 0L, 204L, 36L, 230L, 217L, 37L, 62L, 
    41L, 30L, 64L, 25L, 22L, 60L, 150L, 30L, 90L, 109L, 92L, 
    178L), X13 = c(224L, 168L, 120L, 23L, 213L, 310L, 324L, 377L, 
    366L, 212L, 54L, 178L, 0L, 207L, 316L, 105L, 117L, 266L, 
    235L, 106L, 231L, 186L, 147L, 223L, 109L, 182L, 211L, 183L, 
    130L, 132L), X14 = c(66L, 22L, 77L, 204L, 23L, 143L, 93L, 
    171L, 259L, 37L, 182L, 68L, 218L, 0L, 216L, 186L, 56L, 139L, 
    65L, 44L, 118L, 64L, 19L, 112L, 183L, 14L, 40L, 142L, 96L, 
    131L), X15 = c(167L, 236L, 263L, 275L, 187L, 189L, 212L, 
    282L, 9L, 181L, 309L, 231L, 340L, 238L, 0L, 207L, 216L, 97L, 
    204L, 237L, 120L, 160L, 217L, 188L, 258L, 203L, 183L, 106L, 
    174L, 267L), X16 = c(173L, 196L, 161L, 152L, 168L, 268L, 
    322L, 280L, 265L, 230L, 133L, 160L, 102L, 209L, 193L, 0L, 
    162L, 168L, 228L, 208L, 283L, 159L, 195L, 270L, 14L, 233L, 
    176L, 172L, 48L, 38L), X17 = c(70L, 44L, 13L, 184L, 90L, 
    186L, 194L, 267L, 257L, 72L, 179L, 38L, 107L, 88L, 177L, 
    172L, 0L, 93L, 71L, 14L, 167L, 117L, 37L, 146L, 116L, 35L, 
    62L, 83L, 93L, 129L), X18 = c(115L, 128L, 153L, 196L, 78L, 
    109L, 147L, 185L, 103L, 138L, 218L, 123L, 200L, 85L, 91L, 
    178L, 86L, 0L, 35L, 125L, 67L, 68L, 142L, 42L, 202L, 84L, 
    81L, 91L, 87L, 210L), X19 = c(36L, 104L, 71L, 166L, 16L, 
    99L, 88L, 133L, 200L, 35L, 246L, 2L, 263L, 89L, 144L, 229L, 
    47L, 103L, 0L, 31L, 114L, 32L, 44L, 106L, 219L, 43L, 92L, 
    119L, 150L, 103L), X20 = c(74L, 66L, 22L, 101L, 76L, 101L, 
    194L, 211L, 170L, 21L, 179L, 105L, 197L, 36L, 180L, 204L, 
    48L, 71L, 59L, 0L, 178L, 32L, 58L, 125L, 180L, 46L, 16L, 
    77L, 130L, 75L), X21 = c(85L, 158L, 144L, 210L, 29L, 16L, 
    44L, 65L, 141L, 88L, 258L, 70L, 279L, 124L, 168L, 190L, 145L, 
    45L, 40L, 110L, 0L, 129L, 157L, 52L, 177L, 117L, 175L, 153L, 
    133L, 190L), X22 = c(25L, 44L, 124L, 236L, 62L, 39L, 108L, 
    149L, 175L, 18L, 177L, 16L, 259L, 44L, 163L, 179L, 74L, 110L, 
    28L, 104L, 110L, 0L, 97L, 123L, 216L, 5L, 112L, 170L, 153L, 
    196L), X23 = c(26L, 2L, 39L, 205L, 102L, 74L, 205L, 203L, 
    257L, 49L, 194L, 96L, 207L, 5L, 174L, 160L, 37L, 159L, 55L, 
    55L, 91L, 1L, 0L, 153L, 216L, 52L, 11L, 192L, 116L, 149L), 
    X24 = c(12L, 127L, 115L, 288L, 90L, 60L, 73L, 79L, 194L, 
    87L, 203L, 81L, 257L, 108L, 188L, 263L, 185L, 90L, 25L, 177L, 
    51L, 85L, 93L, 0L, 234L, 114L, 111L, 72L, 131L, 153L), X25 = c(194L, 
    120L, 191L, 143L, 212L, 253L, 281L, 318L, 291L, 160L, 108L, 
    174L, 94L, 188L, 203L, 43L, 127L, 153L, 204L, 162L, 170L, 
    237L, 194L, 251L, 0L, 237L, 122L, 149L, 75L, 104L), X26 = c(10L, 
    58L, 22L, 171L, 101L, 131L, 144L, 154L, 177L, 5L, 222L, 48L, 
    220L, 59L, 192L, 193L, 9L, 134L, 23L, 80L, 75L, 19L, 19L, 
    132L, 197L, 0L, 57L, 146L, 163L, 154L), X27 = c(104L, 58L, 
    15L, 175L, 46L, 178L, 206L, 185L, 199L, 44L, 191L, 115L, 
    211L, 33L, 200L, 148L, 25L, 104L, 47L, 8L, 154L, 35L, 41L, 
    106L, 159L, 14L, 0L, 171L, 88L, 87L), X28 = c(80L, 137L, 
    93L, 225L, 76L, 138L, 245L, 195L, 102L, 130L, 197L, 112L, 
    169L, 163L, 68L, 83L, 108L, 50L, 125L, 108L, 139L, 106L, 
    131L, 111L, 136L, 179L, 150L, 0L, 103L, 151L), X29 = c(170L, 
    113L, 89L, 120L, 138L, 172L, 224L, 263L, 233L, 155L, 170L, 
    132L, 194L, 133L, 160L, 99L, 106L, 86L, 154L, 90L, 132L, 
    158L, 142L, 209L, 55L, 127L, 118L, 93L, 0L, 67L), X30 = c(197L, 
    170L, 155L, 66L, 178L, 193L, 226L, 303L, 213L, 161L, 104L, 
    94L, 140L, 138L, 241L, 29L, 102L, 131L, 108L, 129L, 182L, 
    167L, 167L, 198L, 83L, 154L, 89L, 106L, 87L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Comment: You're probably going to have to post the data if you want concrete help here. You have posted a _picture_ of data, which we can't copy-paste to reproduce your problem. Perhaps `dput` would help here?

Comment: If you are going to post homework questions you will need to show that you have made some effort to solve it.

Comment: Well I was thinking of creating 30 times a 30x30 dataframe in which each column is checked for the optimal solution. The thing is, I do not understand what is meant with the nodes and intermediaries. If someone could just help me with understanding this part, I might find the rest of the solution by myself.

Comment: Since the matrix is square, I might assume the "from" ID is the row number and the "to" ID is the column number. It isn't symmetric, meaning the time from customer 1 to customer 2 is not the same as the time from customer 2 to customer 1. Notice a route can be shortened by visiting one or more other customers on the way. For example, going directly from 1 to 2 is 37, but going from 1 to 22 to 2 is 25 + 9 = 34.

Comment: Take a look at the `igraph` package.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment to use the `igraph` package, below is a way to accomplish what is described.

```
library(igraph)

m <- data.frame(X1 = c(0L, 98L, 132L, 245L, 17L, 69L, 139L, 112L, 207L, 35L, 249L, 43L, 215L, 62L, 152L, 237L, 59L, 119L, 45L, 59L, 23L, 12L, 16L, 66L, 177L, 31L, 118L, 165L, 117L, 193L),
                X2 = c(37L, 0L, 74L, 176L, 91L, 111L, 143L, 208L, 202L, 40L, 172L, 101L, 163L, 51L, 220L, 180L, 48L, 98L, 45L, 62L, 91L, 9L, 50L, 145L, 198L, 48L, 3L, 163L, 159L, 176L),
                X3 = c(118L, 10L, 0L, 138L, 108L, 115L, 221L, 274L, 231L, 89L, 197L, 36L, 175L, 93L, 174L, 184L, 13L, 109L, 109L, 22L, 172L, 91L, 12L, 149L, 140L, 108L, 8L, 133L, 168L, 139L),
                X4 = c(252L, 137L, 112L, 0L, 248L, 276L, 373L, 350L, 353L, 137L, 31L, 186L, 49L, 170L, 325L, 81L, 117L, 184L, 175L, 185L, 279L, 182L, 120L, 205L, 130L, 132L, 133L, 226L, 158L, 67L),
                X5 = c(40L, 93L, 118L, 188L, 0L, 38L, 147L, 106L, 208L, 46L, 228L, 26L, 208L, 54L, 163L, 212L, 81L, 49L, 45L, 84L, 12L, 82L, 114L, 81L, 173L, 67L, 52L, 63L, 146L, 156L),
                X6 = c(54L, 117L, 143L, 296L, 74L, 0L, 78L, 97L, 218L, 52L, 239L, 47L, 267L, 111L, 216L, 269L, 167L, 91L, 105L, 99L, 16L, 117L, 95L, 15L, 264L, 136L, 148L, 100L, 145L, 242L),
                X7 = c(143L, 145L, 208L, 302L, 130L, 86L, 0L, 84L, 308L, 151L, 348L, 102L, 305L, 139L, 254L, 272L, 156L, 182L, 87L, 214L, 110L, 82L, 145L, 59L, 283L, 98L, 171L, 192L, 211L, 228L),
                X8 = c(142L, 195L, 238L, 336L, 161L, 80L, 2L, 0L, 289L, 135L, 342L, 134L, 307L, 169L, 197L, 347L, 261L, 143L, 128L, 243L, 52L, 128L, 169L, 97L, 318L, 214L, 229L, 225L, 287L, 288L),
                X9 = c(230L, 238L, 217L, 264L, 229L, 154L, 299L, 269L, 0L, 210L, 335L, 204L, 342L, 260L, 25L, 258L, 264L, 76L, 170L, 222L, 126L, 193L, 272L, 203L, 218L, 186L, 214L, 120L, 240L, 207L),
                X10 = c(2L, 30L, 34L, 186L, 75L, 96L, 161L, 179L, 244L, 0L, 199L, 17L, 181L, 59L, 240L, 178L, 101L, 117L, 1L, 48L, 79L, 72L, 24L, 60L, 236L, 5L, 32L, 151L, 203L, 133L),
                X11 = c(243L, 191L, 114L, 38L, 164L, 211L, 295L, 370L, 350L, 211L, 0L, 174L, 14L, 166L, 278L, 164L, 165L, 223L, 252L, 129L, 201L, 196L, 201L, 271L, 98L, 199L, 209L, 219L, 168L, 62L),
                X12 = c(22L, 14L, 64L, 164L, 68L, 113L, 117L, 115L, 208L, 8L, 239L, 0L, 204L, 36L, 230L, 217L, 37L, 62L, 41L, 30L, 64L, 25L, 22L, 60L, 150L, 30L, 90L, 109L, 92L, 178L),
                X13 = c(224L, 168L, 120L, 23L, 213L, 310L, 324L, 377L, 366L, 212L, 54L, 178L, 0L, 207L, 316L, 105L, 117L, 266L, 235L, 106L, 231L, 186L, 147L, 223L, 109L, 182L, 211L, 183L, 130L, 132L),
                X14 = c(66L, 22L, 77L, 204L, 23L, 143L, 93L, 171L, 259L, 37L, 182L, 68L, 218L, 0L, 216L, 186L, 56L, 139L, 65L, 44L, 118L, 64L, 19L, 112L, 183L, 14L, 40L, 142L, 96L, 131L),
                X15 = c(167L, 236L, 263L, 275L, 187L, 189L, 212L, 282L, 9L, 181L, 309L, 231L, 340L, 238L, 0L, 207L, 216L, 97L, 204L, 237L, 120L, 160L, 217L, 188L, 258L, 203L, 183L, 106L, 174L, 267L),
                X16 = c(173L, 196L, 161L, 152L, 168L, 268L, 322L, 280L, 265L, 230L, 133L, 160L, 102L, 209L, 193L, 0L, 162L, 168L, 228L, 208L, 283L, 159L, 195L, 270L, 14L, 233L, 176L, 172L, 48L, 38L),
                X17 = c(70L, 44L, 13L, 184L, 90L, 186L, 194L, 267L, 257L, 72L, 179L, 38L, 107L, 88L, 177L, 172L, 0L, 93L, 71L, 14L, 167L, 117L, 37L, 146L, 116L, 35L, 62L, 83L, 93L, 129L),
                X18 = c(115L, 128L, 153L, 196L, 78L, 109L, 147L, 185L, 103L, 138L, 218L, 123L, 200L, 85L, 91L, 178L, 86L, 0L, 35L, 125L, 67L, 68L, 142L, 42L, 202L, 84L, 81L, 91L, 87L, 210L),
                X19 = c(36L, 104L, 71L, 166L, 16L, 99L, 88L, 133L, 200L, 35L, 246L, 2L, 263L, 89L, 144L, 229L, 47L, 103L, 0L, 31L, 114L, 32L, 44L, 106L, 219L, 43L, 92L, 119L, 150L, 103L),
                X20 = c(74L, 66L, 22L, 101L, 76L, 101L, 194L, 211L, 170L, 21L, 179L, 105L, 197L, 36L, 180L, 204L, 48L, 71L, 59L, 0L, 178L, 32L, 58L, 125L, 180L, 46L, 16L, 77L, 130L, 75L),
                X21 = c(85L, 158L, 144L, 210L, 29L, 16L, 44L, 65L, 141L, 88L, 258L, 70L, 279L, 124L, 168L, 190L, 145L, 45L, 40L, 110L, 0L, 129L, 157L, 52L, 177L, 117L, 175L, 153L, 133L, 190L),
                X22 = c(25L, 44L, 124L, 236L, 62L, 39L, 108L, 149L, 175L, 18L, 177L, 16L, 259L, 44L, 163L, 179L, 74L, 110L, 28L, 104L, 110L, 0L, 97L, 123L, 216L, 5L, 112L, 170L, 153L, 196L),
                X23 = c(26L, 2L, 39L, 205L, 102L, 74L, 205L, 203L, 257L, 49L, 194L, 96L, 207L, 5L, 174L, 160L, 37L, 159L, 55L, 55L, 91L, 1L, 0L, 153L, 216L, 52L, 11L, 192L, 116L, 149L),
                X24 = c(12L, 127L, 115L, 288L, 90L, 60L, 73L, 79L, 194L, 87L, 203L, 81L, 257L, 108L, 188L, 263L, 185L, 90L, 25L, 177L, 51L, 85L, 93L, 0L, 234L, 114L, 111L, 72L, 131L, 153L),
                X25 = c(194L, 120L, 191L, 143L, 212L, 253L, 281L, 318L, 291L, 160L, 108L, 174L, 94L, 188L, 203L, 43L, 127L, 153L, 204L, 162L, 170L, 237L, 194L, 251L, 0L, 237L, 122L, 149L, 75L, 104L),
                X26 = c(10L, 58L, 22L, 171L, 101L, 131L, 144L, 154L, 177L, 5L, 222L, 48L, 220L, 59L, 192L, 193L, 9L, 134L, 23L, 80L, 75L, 19L, 19L, 132L, 197L, 0L, 57L, 146L, 163L, 154L),
                X27 = c(104L, 58L, 15L, 175L, 46L, 178L, 206L, 185L, 199L, 44L, 191L, 115L, 211L, 33L, 200L, 148L, 25L, 104L, 47L, 8L, 154L, 35L, 41L, 106L, 159L, 14L, 0L, 171L, 88L, 87L),
                X28 = c(80L, 137L, 93L, 225L, 76L, 138L, 245L, 195L, 102L, 130L, 197L, 112L, 169L, 163L, 68L, 83L, 108L, 50L, 125L, 108L, 139L, 106L, 131L, 111L, 136L, 179L, 150L, 0L, 103L, 151L),
                X29 = c(170L, 113L, 89L, 120L, 138L, 172L, 224L, 263L, 233L, 155L, 170L, 132L, 194L, 133L, 160L, 99L, 106L, 86L, 154L, 90L, 132L, 158L, 142L, 209L, 55L, 127L, 118L, 93L, 0L, 67L),
                X30 = c(197L, 170L, 155L, 66L, 178L, 193L, 226L, 303L, 213L, 161L, 104L, 94L, 140L, 138L, 241L, 29L, 102L, 131L, 108L, 129L, 182L, 167L, 167L, 198L, 83L, 154L, 89L, 106L, 87L, 0L))
system.time({
  g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(m), "directed", TRUE, FALSE)
  mOpt <- shortest.paths(g, V(g), V(g), mode = "out")
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>       0       0       0
mOpt[1:10, 1:10]
#>      X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10
#> X1    0  21  25 133  36  27  71  73 123   2
#> X2   18   0  10 122  40  45  89  91 127  17
#> X3   36  18   0 112  58  63 107 109 145  27
#> X4  130 112 117   0 152 157 201 203 239 129
#> X5   17  36  40 148   0  44  88  81 127  17
#> X6   39  48  52 160  28   0  86  68 142  41
#> X7   67  88  92 200  56  60   0   2 170  69
#> X8   88 109 113 221  77  81  84   0 191  90
#> X9  157 165 170 250 140 157 208 193   0 154
#> X10  22  19  23 131  34  49  92  94 121   0
mOptPaths <- lapply(V(g), function(from) all_shortest_paths(g, from = from, mode = "out"))
# optimal path from 1 to 2
(path_1_2 <- as.integer(mOptPaths[[1]]$res[[2]]))
#> [1]  1 10 26 22  2
# distances for path from 1 to 2
m[matrix(c(head(path_1_2, -1), path_1_2[-1]), ncol = 2)]
#> [1] 2 5 5 9
```